# TypeError: ReactHtmlParser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with react-html--parser to convert HTML string to actual HTML. I am working with Next.js.

My code:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ReactHtmlParser = dynamic(
    () => {
      return import('react-html-parser');
    },
    { ssr: false }
);

export default function Profile({ profileData }) {

  const ExtendedProfileShow = [
        profileData.businessInfo.extendedProfile.map((showExtendedProfile) => 
            <div key={showExtendedProfile.title}> {showExtendedProfile.title} <br/> 
                {showExtendedProfile.info} 
            </div>)
    ];

return (
  <div>
    {ReactHtmlParser(ExtendedProfileShow)}
  </div>
);

}
```

After trying this, I got an error: `TypeError: ReactHtmlParser is not a function`

[image: The Error]

Comment: As the error suggests, `ReactHtmlParser` is not a function - it's a component. Next.js dynamic import returns a React component.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delayed response!
**Instead of this**

```
const ReactHtmlParser = dynamic(
    () => {
      return import('react-html-parser');
    },
    { ssr: false }
);
```

**Use this**

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
```

**Instead of this**

```
{ReactHtmlParser(ExtendedProfileShow)}
```

**Use This**

```
{ReactHtmlParser(`${ExtendedProfileShow}`)}
```